# Unable to install web3 js for windows10

Tags: solidity, web3js

The problem is to unable to install web3 js for windows10. I tried to install the latest version of Web3 js using the command:

```
npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.46
```

The error in terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\RSky> npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.46

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Users\RSky\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Users\RSky\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\RSky\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\RSky\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\RSky\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nan'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:119:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:589:27)
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\RSky\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\RSky\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\RSky\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\RSky\package.json'
npm WARN RSky No description
npm WARN RSky No repository field.
npm WARN RSky No README data
npm WARN RSky No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RSky\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-05T18_04_48_554Z-debug.log
```

What the cause of that error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
window.contractInstance = new web3.eth.contract(abi, myContractAddress)
```

With

```
window.contractInstance = new window.web3.eth.contract(abi, myContractAddress)
```

Comment: Please update the question with your configuration, inputs, expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this new line of code didn't help so far, so I kinda lost with the same errors at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

in contract you have

```
    constructor() public {
        owner == msg.sender;
    }
```

is it correct?

shouldn't it be

```
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
    // Web3.js instance
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

you are writing `web3.currentProvider`. But in your code `web3` is not declared anywhere. Is it declared in `head`?

From your code I understand that you are not using `metamask`. If we use metamask it injects a version of web3 library into a page. We can use it to get a web3 instance like

```
    var web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

But if we are not using metamask we need to use a 3rd party provider to get the web3 instance like `infura` and the above line of code will change to

```
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<<your infura token>>"));
```

**UPDATE 2:**

change

```
    // Contract instance
    window.contractInstance = new window.web3.eth.contract(abi,myContractAddress)

    contractInstance.owner((err, ownerValue) => {
        document.querySelector('#owner-address').innerHTML(ownerValue)
    })
```

to

```
    // Contract instance
    window.contractInstance = window.web3.eth.contract(abi).at(myContractAddress)

    contractInstance.owner((err, ownerValue) => {
        document.querySelector('#owner-address').innerHTML = ownerValue;
    })
```

I deployed same contract on Rinkeby test net and its working. Contract address `0x104ec30CD6FDC5889eDff672b7ac8a2a42232F64`

**UPDATE 3:**

Question was edited and now this answer doesn't go with the question.

Comment: right, but it's didn't fix this issue in Chrome "contractInstance.owner is not a function" and in Microsoft Edge, it keeps telling me "'web3' is not defined"

Comment: I'm using MetaMask Ropsten Test Network and all transaction I got, is perfectly fine because it gives the myContractAddress = "0x50c57b9eb3c4fe581016f1e5d507e3daba3fd26d" so I have no problem with that. My  Web3.js declared  as  the <script src="web3.js"></script> you can see it after </body> tag Do you think I have to declare it upper in the head?

Comment: Found a solution for your issue. Edited my answer. On a side note you are using **web3** version `0.20.x`. Please consider using  `1.0.0-beta.x`. For web3 0.20.x api list you visit: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethblocknumber

Comment: The problem is, to unable to install web3 js into the project. So I'm trying to find the solution how to fix it. Any ideas kindly appreciated!

Comment: try `npm install --global windows-build-tools` and then install web3.

Comment: `windows-build-tools` should have downloaded all the missing dependencies for `web3` including `nan`. Try to install `nan` first then with `npm install --save nan`